# QGIS 3.10 drop-drown list (value relation)

Tags: qgis, csv, vector-field

I am using QGIS 3.10. I created a field with a drop-drown list of 10 country names (using an imported csv file)  . Is there an option to add a country that does not inculded in the list manually without updating the list itself? The field is a widget type "value relation".

@sn1ks I want to add a new value when I open the feature form.

Comment: please specify a little bit more: do you want to be able to add a new value in the dropdown menu when you open the feature form? or is it enough to be able to edit the imported value list within qgis?